# Spring AOP. can anyone elobarate with simple example that what is AOP and the purpose, Advices, Target, and interceptor names

Tags: spring, spring-aop

What the terms added into the AOP, so that we are calling it Cross Cutting Concern.
Difference between Interceptor and AOP.

-This question is for lil bit discussion on AOP and Interceptor but please elobarate.

Comment: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

Answer (score 1):

`Interceptors` are part of Spring framework which allow you to write logic by intercepting requests/calls in between the route. There are mainly 2 kinds of `Interceptors` in `Spring`.

`Handler Interceptors`, present in `Spring MVC` framework, are used to include your interceptor logic for web requests, whereas `Method Interceptors`, within `Spring AOP` framework, are generic in nature and not just limited to intercept HTTP requests.

When comparing `AOP` with `Interceptors`, I can say, in one line, that these `Method Interceptors` are the base understanding behind writing `aspects` in `AOP`.

`AOP`, aka Aspect Oriented Programing, is a bit complex subject to be explained in a StackOverflow answer. I would suggest you to read for it on internet and make yourself comfortable with the basics & `AOP` terminology before entering into Aspect Oriented Programing.

Below is one good resource to understand the dynamic proxy in Spring AOP and fundamentals of it.

[Understanding Dynamic Proxy: Spring AOP Basics](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/04/understanding-dynamic-proxy-spring-aop-basics.html)

**Update**

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-cutting_concern) has a very simple yet effective definition & example for Cross-Cutting Concern.

> In Aspect-oriented software development, cross-cutting concerns are
>   aspects of a program that affect other concerns. These concerns often
>   cannot be cleanly decomposed from the rest of the system in both the
>   design and implementation, and can result in either scattering (code
>   duplication), tangling (significant dependencies between systems), or
>   both.
>
> For instance, if writing an application for handling medical records,
>   the indexing of such records is a core concern, while logging a
>   history of changes to the record database or user database, or an
>   authentication system, would be cross-cutting concerns since they
>   touch more parts of the program.

AOP with Spring Framework is described in a very simple manner at this [article](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/aop_with_spring.htm) of TutorialsPoint which would help you get familiar with all the basic terminologies of Spring AOP.

Comment: thank you so much :) its enough. But i want to know one more thing that
What type of advice we are giving in AOP. what does it mean. Advices and joinPoint and what does mean of cross cutting functionality.

Thanks again :) I will go thrugh document also for better understanding.

Comment: Updated the answer with more details.